# Interface with Xbee pro-S2C with raspberry pi to set frequency parameters

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, xbee, zigbee, node-xbee

Is it possible to set the frequency parameters of [Xbee pro-S2C](https://store.ncd.io/product/zigbee-mesh-xbee-pro-long-range-wireless-mesh-communications-module-external-antenna/) or will it work on default settings only? 
If yes, any sample available which will help me to create this kind solution with python code? 
I am connecting Xbee with Raspberry pi by using micro USB shield.
Your advice on this will be helpful.

Comment: What are the "Frequency Parameters" that you're referring to?  You can use XCTU on a PC to configure the module, or you can use a terminal program on the Pi to enter command mode and send AT commands to configure it.  Digi also has a Python library to interface with the module: https://github.com/digidotcom/python-xbee

Comment: I want to set some frequency range only on which sensor will able to talk to the receiver and the frequency range can be set automatically or manually as per my requirement.

Comment: I guess it isn't clear what frequencies you expect to use.  The S2C uses 802.15.4 which describes specific channels for communicating at 250kbps.  You can use the `ATSC` command to limit the channels the module uses to form (as a coordinator) or join (as a router or end device) a network.